# Byte array Properties C#

Tags: c#, properties, .net-core, byte

I have an object like this:

```
public class CustomObject{

    public byte[] FieldA {private get; set;}
    public IPAddreess FieldB {private get; set;}

}
```

FieldA is the byte rappresentation of FieldB.

I create this object from two sources of data.
 One from a binary file where i need to be fast, then i prefer to set only the FieldA. The other one is in an application where i retrieve the data only in "FieldB format".

I want a function like this:

```
public IPAddress GetField(){
   if (FieldB != null)
       return FieldB;
   FieldB = new IPAddress(FieldA);
   return FieldB;
}
```

To simplify i used an IPAddress conversion, but usually i have more complex operations to do.

Is this the correct way to do this? Or there is some other method that can simplify this one? I'm using .NET CORE Thank you in advance

Comment: Having code in getter / setter methods is generally a bad idea. Not only is code smell, but in the future you will forget there was code in them and it will cause trouble.

Comment: Ok thank you, but if i have a complex operations to do this makes get and set too much large and complex to read, or not?

Comment: @bradbury9 Why then properties exist at all? You can just use fields instead.

Comment: @bradbury9 setters _do_ exist to have code in them. They should not have side effects of perform expensive calculations (let alone I/O), but this is fine. See for example [Should Properties have side effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82377/should-properties-have-side-effects).

Comment: If you need complex operations in your getter/setters you will probably need to rethink your design a bit (events and functions could be needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in `FieldB`'s getter, without explicitly writing a get-method:

```
private IPAddreess _fieldB;
public IPAddreess FieldB 
{
    get
    {
        if (_fieldB == null)
        {
            _fieldB = new IPAddress(FieldA);
        }
        return _fieldB;
    }
    set
    {
        _fieldB = value;
    }
}
```

This code uses a private backing field `_fieldB` for storing the property's value. Upon retrieving the property, it'll either return the value already stored in the field, or assign it based on `FieldA`'s contents and then return it.